# cakephp 2.x cant login using official tutorial

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I'm using CakePHP 2.2, here is the link to tutorial that I used: [**link**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html)

Very important: **I turned off Inflector**

I don't care about ACL(it works :D), my AUTH doesn't work... `$this->Auth->login()` returns false...

Users controller:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    public $components = array('Auth' => array('authenticate' => array('form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'login')))),'Session');

    function beforeFilter() {

        //$this->Auth->allow('logout', 'view');
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
        parent::beforeFilter(); 

    }
    function login() {
        if ($this->Auth->login())
        {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
```

App controller:

```
App::uses('Alc', 'Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array('Auth'=>array('authorize' => array('Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers'))), 'Session');

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

    function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->userModel = 'Users';
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'admin', 'edit', 'login', 'logout', 'add');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'novosti', 'action' => 'index');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'novosti', 'action' => 'index');
    }
```

Users Model:

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class Users extends AppModel {
        public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
            if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
                $this->data['Users']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['Users']['password']);
            }
            return true;
        }
        public function bindNode($user) {
            return array('model' => 'Groups', 'foreign_key' => $user['Users']['groups_id']);
        }
```

View file:

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create('Users', array('action' => 'login'));
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'legend' => __('Login', true),
    'Login',
    'password'
));
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

**NO SQL DUMPS AVAILABLE**

I went to `lib/controller/components/Authcomponents.php` and to `lib/controller/components/auth/*` and look though all those files.... and changed all `Auth.User` to `Auth.Users`; also looked though setting variables and everywhere I found I changed the model name from `User` to `Users`, and also for login fields a changed from `username` to `Login`

Comment: Why did you "turn off" Inflector? Isn't it a core library for determining class names and file names in the CakePHP core?

Comment: becouse i wanna use russian names for model names etc... when u turn it off all works fine... i mean the whole cakephp thing uses it and when u turn offf it doesnt so even bake comand bakes me all my tables correct... and really all works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in login view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create('Users', array('action' => 'login')); 
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'legend' => __('Login', true),
    'username',
    'password'
));
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

Auth accepts default authorize fileds as username/password if you want to use login then override auth authorization like this in controller:

```
$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'login', 'password' => 'password');
```

or in controller you can do this:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
'Form' => array(
'fields' => array('username' => 'login', 'password' =>'password')
    )
        );
if($this->Auth->login($this->request->data['Users'])){
        ......your code...
    }
```

Comment: i added this line beforeFilter is that correct? it didnt help... im screwed %(

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. Passing an argument to Auth doesn't authenticate the user! If you passed in `$this->Auth->login('fakedata');` it would still return true

Comment: Its not incorrect answer you could clear your doubt by reading this.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

Answer (score 2):

`if (debug($this->Auth->login()))`

Debug doesn't returning anything so this line will always fail.

Your usename is field is `Login` but the default is `username` and you haven't configured Auth for this.

```
public $components = [
    'Auth' => [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'Users',
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'Login'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

In your beforeSave you're using `Users` key rather than `User`. Model is singular.

Add `<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>` and look at the query generated. Make sure it is correct and the password matches with your database value.

Just some stuff I noticed.

Comment: about debug... i know... i putted that line to test if i put it away still it will return false... about singular/plurar - i turned off inflector... and abiut the configure Auth component... can u tell how to do this mate?

Comment: Well, what's your username field in your database. Is it actually "Login"?

Comment: where should add 'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'Login'
                ],
            ],
        ], - i mean a have this line in UsersController or Appcontroller?... the dump says nothing

Comment: It's in my answer, in the $components array under Auth key

Comment: Update your question with the query generated via the sql_dump I mentioned. If its failing its either using the wrong fields or your password hashing is incorrect. So check on that

Comment: I think the problem is in Inflector and the Login field... you r right... but just cant fix it(((